# Do I need an EQ pedal if I have an audio interface for bass?

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces, guitar, bass

I have an audio interface for my bass but I was wondering if I need an EQ pedal even though I have audio and interface.

Comment: You don't need an EQ pedal to record your bass, just plug it directly into your audio interface. Unless you want to alter the sound of your bass while recording, this is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **need** any pedals.
Pedals are all about *want* not *need*, especially on bass. Guitarists 'need' some pedals to get specific sounds. Bassists generally don't, assuming your bass & amp [or virtual amp model] are sufficiently flexible.

In 50 years of bass playing, I fell for the GAS* once, about 45 years ago. I used it for a couple of gigs & never bothered again.

*GAS = Gear Acquisition Syndrome.
Affects us all. There must be *one* cool new toy we could add to the rig.
*(BassBalls …envelope follower with optional distortion, if you must know. I have no idea now why my 15-year-old self thought it might be useful;)*